# Flex container's width doesn't expand when flex item is styled by aspect-ratio

Tags: css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I want to make a square element `#board` responsive.

Unfortunately, in landscape view, the flex container `#wrap` doesn't expand it's width to the width of the flex item `#board`. When I apply a fixed width and height to `#board` it does, thus the reason seems to be the `aspect-ratio`.

What's the reason for this, did I do anything wrong? How can I fix it?

I used this HTML and CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 26%, rgba(89, 177, 185, 1) 100%);
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#timer,
#home {
  font-size: 7.5vh;
}

#board {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
  <div id="board"></div>
  <div id="home">Home</div>
</div>
```

Comment: #wrap should expand it's width to that of #board.

Comment: it does though? in portrait mode, I get a horizontal scrollbar because #wrap is expanding

Comment: My bad, the issue occurs in landscape mode, I edited my posting.

Comment: In landscape, aspect ratio is 1:1. This means it must be a square. So #board is limited by the shorter dimension (height). So in landscape, the width of #board will stay the same as the height.
#wrap doesn't need to expand because the width of #board is smaller than the width of #wrap. I'm still confused by what you need

Comment: In landscape, #board is a square in the middle - correct because aspect ratio 1:1. The width of #wrap is full-width. What needs to expand?

Comment: "The width of #wrap is full-width."
Unfortunately for me it is not. I tested in Opera and Firefox.
Appended a screenshot to my question.

Comment: There we go - suspected it was a browser difference. It works for me in chrome. Can you just set the width of #wrap to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `flex: 1` from `#board` and add `height: 100%` to it instead:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 26%, rgba(89, 177, 185, 1) 100%);
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#timer,
#home {
  font-size: 7.5vh;
}

#board {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
  <div id="board"></div>
  <div id="home">Home</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately there is a gap at the left and the right now. I fixed this by setting align-items to stretch for #wrap.
    Apparently the way browsers are handling aspect-ratio in conjunction with flex layout is still buggy.
    Additionally there is an annoying bug in Opera and Chrome: The final layout is rendered only after resizing in vertical direction.